Unable to find app name. Unable to find executable to run
I am trying to run my Flutter app on MacBook Air with M2 chip for macOS and I'm getting this error during the build.

Unable to find app name. .../macos/Flutter/ephemeral/.app_filename
does not exist Unable to find executable to run Error launching
application on macOS.


Just by opening Runner.xcworkspace on the Xcode got rid of this issue for me.
open macos/Runner.xcworkspace

